# data em javascript em formato errado para o controller c# (Asp net mvc)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, datepicker

Estou com uma situação estranha.

Estou trabalhando com datepicker jquery, Asp net mvc 5.

eu configurei o datepicker para o formato conforme abaixo:

```
 $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        showAnim: 'slideDown',
        duration: 'fast',
        buttonText: "Calendário",
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        showOn: "both",
        buttonImage: "../Content/images/calendario.png",          
        clearBtn: true,
        dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Segunda', 'Terça', 'Quarta', 'Quinta', 'Sexta', 'Sábado', 'Domingo'],
        dayNamesMin: ['D', 'S', 'T', 'Q', 'Q', 'S', 'S', 'D'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sáb', 'Dom'],
        monthNames: ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'],
        onSelect: function () {
            $(this).removeClass('input-validation-error');
            $('#dataDeInicio-error').hide();
        }
    });
```

Ele vem de um multiselect:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DataDeInicioDaQuestao, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @Value = Model.DataDeInicioDaQuestao.HasValue ? Model.DataDeInicioDaQuestao.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") : String.Empty, @class = "datepicker campoData grid_2", @id = "DataDeInicioDaQuestao", maxlength = "10", @readonly = "readonly" })
```

mas quando dou submit no formulário ele manda pro ActionResult a data em formato errado. Então, por exemplo, se eu colocar a data 18/07/2019 ele considera 07/18/2019 e ocorre o erro.

```
public ActionResult ObterRelatorioDeRelatorioDePercentualDeAcertosDaQuestao(DateTime? dataDeInicioDaQuestao, DateTime? dataDeFimDaQuestao, string questao)
    {
        try
        {}
}
```

o que eu faço????

Comment: primeiro mude o seus parametros de `DateTime?` para `string` e veja o formato que está chegando. Dai pode formatar facilmente no C#

Comment: como eu não pensei nisso, né? Funcionou agora. Depois foi só converter a string para data. Muito obrigada!

Comment: boa, datas sempre são um problema.. outra solução seria usar a biblioteca *moment.js* e converter o formato no javascript, tem alguns exemplos aqui no site, funciona bem

Answer (score 0):

**Seu modelo**

```
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "informe sua data.")]
  [DataType(DataType.Date)]
  public DateTime IssueDate { get; set; }
```

**Razor Page**

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.IssueDate)
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IssueDate)
```

**JQuery DatePicker**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#IssueDate').datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
            showStatus: true,
            showWeeks: true,
            currentText: 'Now',
            autoSize: true,
            gotoCurrent: true,
            showAnim: 'blind',
            highlightWeek: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Arquivo Webconfig**

```
<system.web>
    <globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-GB"/>
</system.web>
```

Agora sua caixa de texto aceitará o formato "dd / MM / aaaa" .

Comment: dessa forma infelizmente não funcionou :( mas obrigada pela ajuda!

o que eu fiz foi colocar o parâmetro da data da action como string e depois convertê-la para datetime . Aí funcionou!